# Binary serialized file to an understandable text file

Tags: python

I have a serialized file in python, and I have to unserialize it to a human-understandable file.

The file has no extension and it looks like this:

```
\rß  h†rà  Rrá  h„X   0100cd022904000105001100râ  h†X   2.2.2rã  ubh^h_h`†rä  …rå  Rræ  }rç  (hehf)rè  }ré  (hi‰hjhkubhlJ¨!Ÿ hmX   A81758FFFE051505rê  ho}rë  (X   datarì  }rí  (X   Co2rî  MŸX   Humidityrï  G?×
=p£×
```

I tried to pickle.load() but I don't have the packages required.

Also, when I read it, I got a bytes python object. I tried to decode it to ASCII or UTF-8 but still unreadable.

Code:

```
with open("file", "rb") as f:
    new_data = f.read()
```

Output:

```
b'\x80\x03cval\nVal\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02(X\x05\x00\x00\x00modelq\x03cval\nView\nq\x04X\x03\x00\x00\x00_dbq\x05NX\x06\x00\x00\x00_hintsq\x06}q\x07X\x05\x00\x00\x00queryq\x08cdjango.db.models.sql.query\nQuery\nq\t)
```

Is there a way to use something like pickle without the required packages?

### Update

I have this Python object that needs to be deserialized but I do not have the packages required to use `pickle.load()`

Example of a serialized object:

```
b'\x80\x04\x959\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c5class Foo(object):@propertydef bar(self):return "bar"\x94.'
```

Example of the output after `pickle.loads()`:

```
class Foo(object):
        @property
        def bar(self):
                return "bar"
```

Comment: Give us a clue - what generated the file in the first place?  Python2 or 3 or something else?

Comment: @JasonM Python 3 using pickle.dumps()

Comment: pickle is a core built in.  In Py2 it was called cPickle in Py3 it's just called pickle.  I don't understand why you think you don't have the package for it.

Comment: Ah hang on.  pickle.dumps gets the pickle as a string object.  Did you perhaps write that string to a file using the wrong open().   pickle supports multiple serialisation codings, but if you write the default as a "w" rather than a "wb" it will get corrupted. (cr/lf translations, and null termination)

Comment: @JasonM Sorry, what I don't have are the packages in the file I have to unserialize.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now.  You are trying to create objects of a type you don't have the source code for.  Then obviously you can't create those objects again, but you can parse the file.  Use pickletools.dis() and pick out the data types you do have the code for the classes you need.

Comment: @JasonM Doing it. I am using it like this: ```pickletools.dis(new_data)```, but it's still running due the getting output like this: 3938503: r                LONG_BINPUT 234704

Comment: My answer stands. I am busy now. But if you can't solve this yourself and still need help, post me the pickle file on github (same name) and tell me what data you want to extract I will see if I can find time to look if it's possible.  You may need to understand the internal workings of the class you need to create, that can be very complicated.

Comment: @JayM I appreciate your help so much, I updated the question with a more clear example to help you understand my question easily.

Comment: That example makes no sense.  It's a pickle of a str object instace containing the text of some Python code that would create a class that has no state.  Your prior example as of a django database object. A pickled class object just contains the data in that class (called its state), not the class source code itself.

Comment: The comments here are getting too numerous.  Created a chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/245763/in-a-pickle?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

You can take apart the internals of the data from a pickle file using [pickletools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickletools.html)

```bash
>>> import pickle
>>> import pickletools
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> op = StringIO()
>>> p = pickle.dumps([1,2,3,4])
>>> p
b'\x80\x03]q\x00(K\x01K\x02K\x03K\x04e.'
>>> pickletools.dis(p, out=op)
>>> op.seek(0)
>>> for line in op.read().splitlines():
        print(line)
    0: \x80 PROTO      3
    2: ]    EMPTY_LIST
    3: q    BINPUT     0
    5: (    MARK
    6: K        BININT1    1
    8: K        BININT1    2
   10: K        BININT1    3
   12: K        BININT1    4
   14: e        APPENDS    (MARK at 5)
   15: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 2
>>>
>>> s = ""
>>> op.seek(0)
>>> for line in op.read().splitlines():
        if "BININT1" not in line:
            continue
        s += line.split("BININT1")[1].strip()
>>> pos = op.tell()  # In case we need to write more to the 'file' later
>>> i = int(s)
>>> i
1234
```

Depending on what data you want to extract (if indeed you can extract it).
You would then need to interpret the resulting code using either text processing (as above) or for any complex data structures you would probably need to use a parser.

In the latter case, look at [pyPEG](https://fdik.org/pyPEG/), [parsimonious](https://pypi.org/project/parsimonious/) or [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: After using your code ``` dump = pickletools.dis(new_data)
print(dump)

s = ""
for line in dump: ``` I got the following output referring the dump variable 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I wrote that in the text editor from memory and did not run it. My guess is dump objects don't have a `__repr__` so need to be stingified.

Comment: Ok.  I see the issue, the pickletools.dis() method, though looking like an object is a function and returns None.  Instead you need to use an in-memory file.  Answer updated.